# Running different version in Android library versus your app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following in my main app:

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 19
    versionName "1.0.5"
}
...
```

In a library I use, this is defined:

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 7
}
...
```

I have uppgraded my API target etc. in my app. The library I have, use the same API target etc. (haven't changed the code). If I upgrade my app and use libraries, can I leave them as is? Or do I need to sync the two in respect with compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to update the `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`? You should definetly do that.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I did that for my app. I use a library that i did not write. My *question* is, what are the implications of using a library with other api level etc? And can I leave it as is? (if I do change it in the library I need to test that too I assume).

Comment: I don't know for sure, but most likely the library will be compiled with the build tools and compile version defined in the library's build.gradle and not use the app versions defined in the build.gradle of the app. That of course has all the downsides of not using the newest build tools version and not targeting the newest android version - at least for that library. Since you seem to have access to the source code I suggest you update those two versions manually. It should compile just fine and prevent any problems.

Comment: @XaverKapeller OK. Im not sure what I gain/loose by upgrading compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion? And how does this relate to minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion? I get new build tools ok? I compile towards another version? Pros/Cons...